Understanding the Role of $SO(3)$ in the Derivation of the Schwarzschild Solution
In MTW, the exact derivation of the Schwarzschild solution is based on the following assumptions:

Begin with a manifold $M^4$ on which a metric $ds^2$ of Lorentz signature is defined.
Assume $M^4$ to be spherically symmetric in the sense that to any $3 \times 3$ rotation matrix $A$ there corresponds a mapping (rotation) of $M^4$, also called $A$ ($A:M^4 \to M^4:P \to AP$), that preserves the length of all curves.

In other words, I think this means that the isometry group includes a subgroup isomorphic to $SO(3)$.
By the way, as you know, $SO(3)$ is interpreted as the group formed by all $3 \times 3$ real orthogonal matrices with determinant 1 under matrix multiplication, and its elements represent rotations in an orthogonal coordinate system.
However, in MTW, the "mappings" corresponding to elements of $SO(3)$ are considered instead of matrices and orthogonal coordinates are not mentioned.
Then, it is unclear what is meant by saying that the group isomorphic to $SO(3)$ represents rotations.
Why is it necessary to consider the group isomorphic to $SO(3)$?

Your title and the question inside is basically disconnected. But the simplest answer is that the rotation group is 1) well-established prior to relativity, 2) still applies in that scenario, and 3) helps simplify the equations in order for the usual angular description to be just copied down, leaving the complications to only be functions of some radius. Otherwise, the equations are too difficult to solve.

Your quote is from Box 23.3. I think the emphasis on SO(3) as a mapping (instead of a matrix) is to develop the derivation "geometrically" and "basis-free" as much as possible, until coordinates are needed. Eventually, the notion of "spherical symmetry" will be encoded by a certain set of Killing vector fields.
